# Python - Rename files and give them sequential number

Tags: python

I have quite a few files in this format:

```
file (2009).jpg
file (2010).jpg
file (2011).jpg
```

...etc

and I'd like to have them like this:

```
file (2009) (1).jpg
file (2009) (2).jpg
file (2009) (3).jpg
```

I can handle changing the date:

```
import os, re
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    os.rename(i, re.sub(r'\d{4}', '2009', i))
```

But I can't figure out how to have the sequential number added. I tried using a variable set to 1 and then incremented in the for loop, but I'm doing something wrong:

```
import os, re
n = 1
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    os.rename(i, re.sub(r'\d{4}', '2009', i))
    # use n to increment the filename, but how?
```

Thanks for any assisstance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically change the thing you're substituting in within your loop, like so

```
import os, re
n = 1
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    os.rename(i, re.sub(r'\(\d{4}\)', '(2009) ({n})'.format(n=n), i))
    n += 1
```

Comment: That's cool. Only problem is the result is :`testfile (2009 (1)).jpg`

Comment: @S1M0N_H fixed I think

Comment: Thanks very much Snakes! Really appreciate it.